# I put images under /webapp/img/test.png but it doesn't render in jetty

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, jetty

I added a assets folder and an a images subfolder:

/webapp/assets/img

And inside I put a test.png file.

From inside my index.jsp page, I put a img tag:

```
<img src="/assets/img/test.png" alt="" />
```

The image doesnt' render, I ran:

```
mvn clean install

mvn jetty:run
```

In the output in my terminal window I see:

20:30:42,905  WARN PageNotFound:947 - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/assets/img/test.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp'

I also see the same error for favicon.ico (I dont' have one so that one makes sense).

Do I need to adjust something in my web.xml file?

(This is a spring mvc app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably configured the Spring servlet to be mapped to `/`, which means it handles all the requests to the web app. Either map it to only certain requests (like *.htm, *.action, or whatever), or [configure Spring to serve static resources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-config-static-resources).